# Obtaining the position of a random 1 in an array of 0's in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, indexing, binary-data

I have a matrix which is initialized as follows:

```
stateAndAction = zeros(11, 4);
```

Over time the matrix will be updated so that at a given index, there will be a one. So at any given time we could have something that looks like this

```
1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

How do I find a random row and column with a one in it?

This is the function signature I had in mind:

```
[random_row_index, random_column_index] = findRandom(stateAndAction)
```

Comment: Just a tip: if you know that the array will contain only zeros and ones, might as well define it using `false(11, 4)`. If the array will need to be much bigger and the amount of ones will be less than about 33% of total elements, you can use `false(11, 4, 'like', sparse(false))`. For this matrix size, `sparse` might not provide significant computational benefits, but it helps with visualization a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the position of non-zero elements with find, select a random element and convert index to row/column position in the array:

```
function [random_row_index, random_column_index] = findRandom(stateAndAction)
    ids = find(stateAndAction==1);
    random = randi([1,numel(ids)],1);
    id=ids(random);
    [random_row_index, random_column_index] = ind2sub(size(stateAndAction),id);
end
```